# Custom Analyzer for Haystack

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I using ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7, Django 1.8 & Elasticsearch 2.4.

**search_indexes.py**

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
        text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
        location = indexes.LocationField()

        def get_model(self):
            return Craigslist

        def prepare_location(self, obj):
            # If you're just storing the floats...
            return "%s,%s" % (obj.latitude, obj.longitude)


        def index_queryset(self, using=None):
            """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
            return self.get_model().objects.exclude(latitude__isnull=True).exclude(longitude__isnull=True)
```

I can able to reindex with command

> ./manage.py rebuild_index

While reindex, I got following mapping:

```
{"documents":{"mappings":{"modelresult":{"properties":{"django_ct":{"type":"string"},"django_id":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"location":{"type":"string"},"text":{"type":"string"}}}}}}
```

I got error in logs like:

```
Caused by: [documents] QueryParsingException[failed to find geo_point field [location]]
```

So It raise error because location Field is not a type of 'geo_point'?
After I followed docs, alternate way is to return as Point(longitude, latitude), but it throws serialization error.

How to rebuild index with location in 'geo_point' type?

Please help. I am new to Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0):

while looking at your index mapping, `"location":{"type":"string"}`,
It should have been mapped as following :

```
 "location":{"type":"geo_point"}
```

After implementing this mapping, then try various options to set latitude and longitude values